# Recognize text in an image

Tags: image-processing, ocr

How can I use `TextRecognize` to recognize text in an following image?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? For example, did you try to cut one of the buttons out of the image and run `TextRecognize` on that separately? Could you tell us what language it is? The lighting looks uneven, is the lighting different in different images and if so could you post more images?

Comment: @C.E. The language is Japanese.And you can use `BrightnessEqualize` to get a lighting even image.

Comment: @yode Doesn't seem to work, I'm talking about, for example, the white streak on the leftmost button. Anyway, I was just trying to encourage OP to improve the question. It looks slapdash in its current form.